# PHP: Clean way of checking if a value in a multidimensional associative array equals something

Tags: php, variables, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find a clean way of checking if the value of a dynamically defined is a certain value. It should evaluate true if that variable equals the variable tested against, false if it doesn't match or the variable doesn't exist e.g.:

```
if($array[$with][$some][$depth]==$test)
```

This will evaluate correctly, however it will throw a notice error `if $array[$with][$some][$depth]` isn't actually a variable.

I can't do

```
if(array_key_exists($depth, $array[$with][$some]) && $array[$with][$some][$depth]==$test)
```

as the upper level array might not exist (there could be any number of levels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`isset`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) as a guard. You don't need to do this step-by-step:

```
if(!isset($array[$with][$some][$depth]) || $array[$with][$some][$depth]!=$test) {
    // either does not exist, or has other value
}
```

The only drawback here is that if the value you want to test against is `null`, `isset` will return `false` which is not what you want.

Comment: OK @Jon that works, but now I'm a bit confused as to why. How come the second part of the expression doesn't throw an error if the first bit evaluates to true (key is not set)? Does an if(or) expression immediately break when one preceding element evaluates to true?

Comment: @ZakHenry: Yes. This behavior is called *short circuiting* and is common to many languages. See an explanation [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and the PHP manual [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php).

Comment: Wow thats new to me, thanks for the links. My assumption was that execution evaluated each element, then gave the if statement the result of the || and && operation.

Comment: @ZakHenry: That's the logical assumption. Everyone has to be told when learning their first programming language. :)